# How to fix inserting data into database mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a problem for inserting data in my database.

here is the code. Can you please fix it

```
if (id=="" or Name=="" or Age=="" or Father_Name==""):
    Messagebox.showinfo('info', 'all fields required  You idiot')
else:
    conn= mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="software")
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO information ('id','Name','Age', 'Father Name') VALUES  ('"+ id +"', '"+ Name +"', '"+ Age +"', '"+ Father_Name +"')")
    cursor.execute("commit");

    Messagebox.showinfo("info","Done succesfully");
    conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're quoting the field names in the query. Use backticks not quotes, or nothing. In this case you need backticks because you have space in `Father Name`.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO information (`id`, `Name`, `Age`, `Father Name`) VALUES  ('"+ id +"', '"+ Name +"', '"+ Age +"', '"+ Father_Name +"')")
```

Important: to avoid SQL Injection, do not concatenate user input into the query SQL. Pass the data separately like [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

In general, you should avoid spaces in field names in MySQL.

Comment: Thannk you so much